# Can somebody explain an exclamation mark?

Tags: javascript, syntax

```
    const string = "Hello There";
    const chars ={};

for(let character of string){
  if(!chars[character]){
    chars[character] = 1;
  }else{
    chars[character]++;
  }
}
console.log(chars);
```

The following code will print the number of unique letters appearing in a string. I know that exclamation mark means "false", but I do not understand what it represents in the following example:

```
!chars[character]
```

I have hard time understanding how it characters are compared with other characters since it clearly states char[at a current i].
If somebody could give a much simpler example. I tried debugging it, but couldn't understand as well.

Comment: exclamation mark means "not",    like not chars['H']  => "H" element not exist in chars

Comment: On iterations 0 to 2 ("H", "e",  "l") the condition: `if (!char[character]) {...` -- if ` the object `char` ***DOES NOT*** have a "H" then start one: `char:{"H": 1}`, then second iteration: `char:{"H": 1, "e": 1}` and so on until on the fourth iteration the second condition is met: `else {...` the object `char` ***DOES*** have a "l" -- then add to the count of `char["l"]` -- so on the fourth iteration it will be: `char: {"H":1, "e": 1, "l": 2};`

Comment: @zer00ne u should write it as an answer

Comment: @zer00ne Thank you so much for explaining it in iterations. It was extremely helpful.
I understand now that `chars{}` retains information so it can detect whether there are repeating characters and execute the `else` condition.

Comment: @snr-ReinstateMonica Mr. CP already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61450537/2813224) more or less.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`!` inverts the truthyness of an expression. Since `chars` starts out as an empty object, the first time a character is iterated over, it won't exist on a property of the object; it'll be `undefined`. Eg, for `H`:

```
chars[character]
// equivalent to
chars.H
// resolves to
undefined

// putting ! in front of it makes it truthy instead:
!undefined -> true
```

So `if(!chars[character]){` is saying: if this character doesn't exist on the object yet, then execute the following block:

```
  chars[character] = 1;
} else {
  // The character has already been iterated over;
  // it exists on the object, and the value is a number
  // Increment that number:
  chars[character]++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can the expression into two parts:

1. `chars[character]` returns undefined or the count of characters in the string as a number
2. `!` (Logical (NOT) operator) coerces the next thing to a boolean and then flips the boolean

Therefore the two possible cases:

```js
chars[character] // undefined
Boolean(chars[character]) // false
!chars[character] // true
```

```js
chars[character] // 1
Boolean(chars[character]) // true (numbers other than 0 are coerced to true)
!chars[character] // false
```

[More info at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)